# Spring Batch | How to not create the output file when the job start?

Tags: spring, stream, spring-batch

We have a batch job to check DB data.If the data has any problems,it will write something to the output-file.In another way,it will write nothing.
BUT,what ever the problem has or not,the output-file will created.
And we want it to not create output files when the date is fine.

Here if our xml.

```
<batch:job id="DEFAULT_JOB_ID">
    <batch:step id="step">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" start-limit="100">
            <batch:chunk reader="dbReader01" processor="testProc" writer="classifierWriter01" commit-interval="100" >
                <batch:streams>
                    <batch:stream ref="fileWriter01"/>
                </batch:streams>
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="defaultChunkListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="defaultJobExecutionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<bean id="classifierWriter01" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="classifier">
        <bean class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
            <property name="routerDelegate">
                <bean class="src.test.DefaultClassifier" />
            </property>
            <property name="matcherMap">
                <util:map id="matcherMap" scope="step">
                    <!-- FLAG == 0 THEN write something -->
                    <entry key="0" value-ref="fileWriter01" />
                    <!-- FLAG == 1 THEN write nothing -->
                    <entry key="1" value-ref="dummyWriter" />
                </util:map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fileWriter01" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"   scope="step">
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['outFile']}" />
    <property name="appendAllowed" value="false"/>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="src.test.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="," />
            <property name="allEnclosing" value="true" />
            <property name="enclosure" value='"' />
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor" >
                    <property name="names"
                        value="seq,errCode,errMsg" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
        
<bean id="dummyWriter" class="src.test.DummyItemWriter" scope="step"/>
```

The problem is when we use **FlatFileItemWriter**,we must use **batch:streams** to create the outfile.But if we use **batch:streams**,the outFile will create when the job start.

IF we do not use **batch:streams**,it will throw this errlog
`org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to`

Does itemWriter can not create file by himself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [shouldDeleteIfEmpty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractFileItemWriter.html#setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(boolean)) parameter of the `FlatFileItemWriter` which is designed for this use case.

Comment: Thank a lot.That's what i want.Thank you.